# updating solr document using a query?

Tags: solr

In the solr documentation, there are options to delete documents using a query, something like the following:

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
<delete><query>id:298253</query>
<query>entitytype:BlogEntry</query></delete>
```

However, I could not find any references about updating documents based on a query.  Is this possible with updates in solr?  Basically I would like to update the values of all the documents that match a query.

Something like `update prop1=val1, prop2=val2 where ( prop3 < val3 and prop4=val4 )`

Thanks,
-Vineel

Answer (score 1):

The ability to update documents is being added to the [Solr 4.0](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr4.0) release, which just went into Beta this week. I am not sure if there will be the ability to update documents based on a query, but you could ask in the [Solr Users List](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/discussion.html). Unfortunately, I have not had a chance to explore the 4.0 version yet to see how atomic updates work.

Comment: in the example, it "updates the price where id is 1", is it possible to say 'update price where description="Description 1" and test="test1"

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that for partially updating documents in Solr, they need to be stored. Which increases the index size. Check [this](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/) for some background